# Microsoft Teams app - link unfurling working on web but not desktop or mobile Teams apps

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have created an MS teams bot and app to unfurl public and private links pointing to our web site.

Links are unfurled correctly when using the Teams web app. However when using the Windows or Mac desktop apps, or the Android or iOS mobile apps, no link unfurling happens.

Having debugged the Mac desktop app I can see that no call is made to `https://uk.ng.msg.teams.microsoft.com/v1/agents/28:<our-bot-id>/invoke` to get the unfurled link data from our bot.

Is there additional configuration that is required for our bot and app to be triggered in Teams platforms other than web?

Comment: what kind of link is it that is being unfurled? Is it something that required authentication?

Comment: There's a mixture of public and private links. Public links details are provided by the bot immediately but private links go through the authentication process described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/add-authentication 

Both flows work correctly using the Teams web client, but neither flow works using non-web clients.

Comment: @simonki - Is it possible that the app isn't installed in those other clients? Could you perhaps be logged in with a different account? Have you tried signing out and signing back in on those platforms? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @KyleDelaney - I'm using the same account on both clients. I've also tried installing on both, installing on desktop first, and installing on web first and still get the same behaviour of the unfurl only being triggered from the web client. Signing out and back in is quite often required when using the web client. I've tried the same using the desktop client and still no joy.

Comment: @simoki - we could not reproduce it on our side.Could you please share your app manifest?

Answer (score 0):

As per comments above, I think what's happening is that Teams is trying to "pre-validate" these links on the user's behalf, so to speak. In the browser context, where the user is authenticated, everything is fine, but in the desktop/mobile experience, the user is not authenticated to the backend systems, so the unfurling can't function.

I've not tried this myself, so can't provide much guidance, but it looks like there's a solution to writing your own "unfurler", so to speak. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/link-unfurling?tabs=dotnet).

Comment: We have implemented an unfurler as per that documentation - and like I say it works correctly using the teams web client, but no call to the bot is even made using the desktop and mobile clients. I am going to try re-registering the bot using Azure Bot Services rather than the Bot Framework to see if that helps